# How to get and print how many times a loop spins in a thread before it gets switched to other threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Instead of printing `o` and `-`, I want to print the number of `o` and `-` on the console. However, I have no idea how to get how many times a loop spins in a thread before it gets switched to other threads.

If there are events something likes  `OnLeaving` and `OnEntering` on a thread, I can get the number of spins in the given time slice. Unfortunately, I have no such events.

```
class Program
{
    public const int N = 1000;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadStart ts = DoWork;
        Thread t = new Thread(ts);

        t.Start();


        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++)
        {
            Console.Write('o');
        }

        t.Join();

    }

    private static void DoWork()
    {            
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++)
        {
            Console.Write('-');
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Could you show me how to do this scenario?

Comment: No there are no such events. Threads are inherently unpredictable as to when they actually run. Relying on how many times things are run before switching to another thread *seems* like a bad design, but you may have a reason for doing so? If you want threads to cooperate you need to in some way share state between them and lock the state accordingly. But threads are at their best when the work you split between them may be done in a non sequential order

Comment: You can take two variable named as i and j outside of loop and increment it by 1 inside the loop, it will show you total counts when it enter into loop.

Comment: @AbhayDixit: Show me your code please.

Comment: That's really not too difficult. Just add an int CountI = 0; int CountJ = 0; and object _l = new object(); outside the methods and in the loops do lock(_l) CountI++; and lock(_l) CountJ++; respectively.

Comment: @doubleYou: How do you print the counter? Show me your complete code please.

Comment: @AbhayDixit and doubleYou: I think both of you did not understand my question completely.

Comment: You are right, I misunderstood. @AbhayDixit's comment gets you halfway there, though. I will give you some code in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reiterate: AbhayDixit's comment gives you a cycle counter. You just need to add a locking mechanism and reset the counters after a context switch.

I have modified your code to include a cycle counter. Note that I have increased N significantly. Otherwise, one thread will just run through its 1000 iterations at once - because you no longer have a Write() instruction to slow it down.

```
class Program
{
    public const int N = 1000000;
    private static object _l = new object();

    private static int _i = 0;
    private static int _j = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadStart ts = DoWork;
        Thread t = new Thread(ts);

        t.Start();


        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++)
        {
            lock (_l)
            {
                // j-thread has run?
                if (_j > 0)
                {
                    // print and reset j
                    Console.Write("j{0} ", _j);
                    _j = 0;
                }
                _i++;
            }
        }

        t.Join();

        // print remaining cycles
        // one of the threads will have run after the other has finished and
        // hence not been printed and reset.
        if (_i > 0)
            Console.Write("i{0} ", _i);
        if (_j > 0)
            Console.Write("j{0} ", _j);

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    private static void DoWork()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++)
        {
            lock (_l)
            {
                // i-thread has run?
                if (_i > 0)
                {
                    // print and reset i
                    Console.Write("i{0} ", _i);
                    _i = 0;
                }
                _j++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```